# How do I sum all the items a pointer is pointing to using a while loop

Tags: c

I am doing practice exercises for my coding class and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use a while loop to sum the items my pointer is pointing to. I want to use count to keep track of how many items are being pointed to. I'm not very familiar with pointers as I've just started learning about them. Any help in understanding how to do this would be awesome.

```
(int*)malloc(sizeof(array));
int pointer_sum(int count, int* array){
    while (count > 0) {

    }
}
```

I need to use pointer arithmetic to sum all the items my pointer is pointing to.

Comment: That's not how you use `malloc`.

Comment: Do I not have to allocate memory for the pointer?

Comment: That should have been done *before* you call the function. You do memory allocation(`malloc`) on `array`, fill integers as many as `count` to `array[0]` ... `array[count-1]`, and call the function like `int result; result = pointer_sum(count, array)`.

Answer (score 1):

You know the starting point (*the pointer!*) of the sequence of integers, and you know the length of the sequence with your variable `count`. Then you can use the pointer as if it is a valid *array*.

```c
int pointer_sum(int count, int* array){
    int i, sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you are not to use a `for` loop, you should know that every `for` loop is easily converted to a `while` loop.

```c
int pointer_sum(int count, int* array){
    int i, sum;

    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while(i < count) {
        sum += array[i];
        ++i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you really need to use pointer arithmetic, you should know that you can think `a[i]` works like `*(a+i)`.

```c
int pointer_sum(int count, int* array){
    int i, sum;

    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while(i < count) {
        sum += *(array+i);
        ++i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but I don't understand how to do this with a while loop. When we end up taking our test in a couple of weeks we won't be allowed to use a for loop in this situation.

Comment: okay. I was thinking you had to compare count to the array itself in some way inside the while parameter.

Comment: Check the edit. And for using `malloc` (that's another problem than the main question, though), I think you might want to take another look at your textbook examples or do some Googling.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I know this was a dumb question but I thought pointers had to be compared in some different way. Thanks again!

Comment: One thing that confuses me is we use a program called vocarium to do our exercises and we only write code for the function itself and dont write the main that actually test out function. Sometimes this causes me some confusion when attempting homework and pratice exercises. Thanks for the help.

Comment: now i have to figure out how to get the sum with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: below my code it said I need to use pointer arithmetic. Sorry for not putting it in the main text of the question. Im not that familiar with posting on this site. ive only used it a couple times. sorry

Comment: Well, yeah it's my bad that I missed it. Hope it helped, anyway.

Comment: so basically you are just manually incrementing the array? Is that a proper way to think about it?

Comment: okay. Thanks for your help. i understand this a bit better now

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it looks like the first parameter is the size of the array you've passed in, and the second is a pointer to that array? Assuming that's true, your code would look a bit like this:

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    result += array[i];
}
return result;
```